# ASP.NET Core 2 template missing in VS 2017

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-core-2.0

1. I'm using VS 2017 Community Edition.
   [image: Visual Studio version]
2. I've installed .NET Core 2 SDK from here.
   [image: .NET Core 2 SDK installed from here]
3. When I run `dotnet --version` I get reply like following

[image]

4. But I can't see the `ASP.NET Core 2 template`, instead I see following template.

[image]

How will I get `ASP.NET Core 2 template` like this https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/08/14/announcing-asp-net-core-2-0/#attachment_10076

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The current version of VS 2017 is 15.3.2. Try running the Visual Studio Installer and see if it doesn't offer you an upgrade.

The screenshot of your About-window says it's version 15.0.0. The page you link to states that you need version 15.3.

> This release features compatibility with .NET Core 2.0, tooling support in Visual Studio 2017 version 15.3

Comment: Please give me some time to download & install latest VS. `I'll be back` here again.

Comment: I found the answer here is what worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51017396/685404