# .Net core 2.0 Not showing even after trying multiple recommended fixes

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2017

My visual studio 2017 is not detecting .Net core 2.0 no matter what I do. I am running visual studio 15.4.3 and installed .Net core multiple times with reboots. (no effect)

I tried multiple things like editing the .csproj file and the global.json if it was there (no effect). If I check dotnet --version in my user folder I get "1.0.0-preview2-003121" while if I try it in the "C:\Program Files\dotnet" folder I get "2.0.2"

Even my Environment-variables are not showing any weird path directions to older .Net versions.

Does anyone know a fix  which has not been named in these topics?

1. [ASP.NET Core 2 template missing in VS 2017](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45893545/asp-net-core-2-template-missing-in-vs-2017)
2. [.NET Core 2.0 missing from my Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45778942/net-core-2-0-missing-from-my-visual-studio)

   3. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/61785/net-framework-47-not-listed-as-a-target-framework.html

Every tip is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok after writing the question I realized what the answer was.
As dumb as it sounds I only installed the x64 version and not the x86 so it was never displayed in my SDK folder.

Hopefully this helps another person with the same brain-malfunction =)