# missing “ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)” template

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, .net-core, .net-framework-version

I am trying to develop a ASP.NET Core application. I tried following the [blog](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToReferenceAnExistingNETFrameworkProjectInAnASPNETCore10WebApp.aspx) to understand how references works between .net core and .net framework, but I fail to find the **ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)** in the template dialog as shown below

[image]

I have tried to cross check related [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42959357/asp-net-web-application-net-framework-vs-asp-net-core-web-application-net-f) but they too have ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework) in screenshot attached in their question.

Comment: Try download and run VS installer and check if the necessary packages for .net core development are checked.

Comment: Every component is checked.

Comment: Future readers : For ASP.NET web project templates targeting .NET full framework for cloud/azure - I would encourage you to develope it using .NET Core instead. Microsoft strongly recommends using .NET Core for all your cloud needs. The support for .NET Framework is dimishing with every passing day. Please read - [Choosing between .NET Framework and .NET Core(aka .NET)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Click on **.Net Core** on left side menu. Then you will see all the .net core templates. Select the **ASP.NET Core Web Application** and click Ok.

[image]

After this you will see project template selection dialog. Here you can chose either **.Net Core** or **.Net Framework** for project template.

[image]

Comment: Great. Just curious to know more on these drop downs. How does these affect my applications?

Comment: If you chose .Net Core you application will be .net core app or if you chose .Net Framework then it will be .net core app with full framework.

Comment: so i feel its always better to choose .net core with full .net framework which can be deployed on linux or Mac!

Comment: No it will only deployed on windows.If want to deploy on other OS then you need to create .net core app.

Comment: if that is the case, then why it's showing "ASP.NET Core 2.0" in second dropdown of your screenshot? I am slightly confused. can u send some reference to read

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/choosing-core-framework-server

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ 

Hopefully these links help you.

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/benjaminperkins/2018/02/22/targeting-a-specific-version-of-the-net-framework/

Hopefully you get some information from these links. Please upvote the answer as well thanks.

Comment: Whoever at Microsoft put this option there did a great job of hiding it.

Comment: I have that dropdown disabled, how do I get it enabled?

Comment: We do not see the core web template in the first pic.

Answer (score 8):

After updating to 15.7.4 asp.net core web application template is missing in the project type selection dialog

[image: Cannot see the asp.net core web application template in project type selection screen]

[image: Visual studio install shows that related package is installed]

Comment: For anyone searching, you can bring up the installer easily by going "Tools > Get Tools and features." in VS.

Comment: Alternatively (based on VS 2019) you can launch the installer as a standalone app directly from the Windows start menu. Just hit the Windows key and then type "Visual" and you'll get the VS Installer. Then click "Modify". That'll bring up the second screen in the above.