# Asp.NET Core web application not showing on creation of new project

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

My visual studio 2019 does not show the option to create a project in Asp.NET Core web application (.NET framework). Any suggestions on what to do?

Answer (score 4):

From [`docs`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-aspnet-core?view=vs-2019)

> If you don't see the ASP.NET Core Web App template, Then, in the
> Visual Studio Installer, choose the ASP.NET and web development
> workload.
> [image]
>
> After that, choose the Modify button in the Visual Studio Installer.
> If you're prompted to save your work, do so. Next, choose Continue to
> install the workload. Then, return to step 2 in this "Create a
> project" procedure.

See also: [missing “ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Framework)” template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48941070/missing-asp-net-core-web-application-net-framework-template)

Comment: Correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In visual Studio 2022, you will find everything in separate templates. Templates names are asp.net core web app (empty) or (mvc) or other templates